# Xamarin.Forms - Days to Repeat in a week

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to add something like this to my Xamarin.Forms app, which is generally found in Clock app.

[image: selecting Days of week for repetition]

this should help me decide on which days of the week I should repeat certain tasks.
Kindly let me know on how to do it with C# and XAML.

Comment: Please read "How to Ask" in the help section.  What you posted isn't actually a question.

Comment: Bad, bad question, bro. But you can do it with a grid with seven columns and frames inside each one.

Comment: @Jason sorry guys, I'm a newbie here but as far as I searched I couldn't find the answer for it and so asked a question here.

Comment: @diego  I understand that I can do it with grid and seven columns but I wanted to know is there any standard template as we have it for the Monthly calendar view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick guide, you would start with the following class:

```
public class AlarmDay : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public AlarmDay( string dayOfWeek )
    {
       DayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;       
    }

    public DayOfWeek { get; }

    private bool _isEnabled = false;
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get => _isEnabled;
        set
        {
           _isEnabled = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

You could then use a horizontal list control to which you set a `ItemsSource` with the 7 appropriate instances of `AlarmDay` class. The `DataTemplate` could then contain a custom control, that would contain a `Label` and a `Frame` with corner-radius outline. You then implement `Tap` gesture and update the `IsEnabled` property of the data-bound `AlarmDay` instance (in `BindingContext`) and the `Frame` `BackgroundColor`.